# Proper destruction of pointers to objects

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I would like to ask a couple of quick questions about the proper destruction of int pointers and vector pointers. First, I have seen people ask in the past about these type of problems, and almost always there are several responses about how using vector pointers , pointers to objects ,etc in C++ is not good standard c++ coding practice, and that you should instantiate a copy of the object. That may be true, but you do not always have control of paradigms that have been layed before your arrival. The paradigm I am required to work in requires initializing pointers to almost everything. A very Java like approach to C++. One of the main reasons we do this is our data sets are so large , stack allocations would be subject to overflows.

My questions:

If I have a pointer to a int32_t array, what is the proper way to destroy it in the destructor?

Note: Our practice is to set any pointer to NULL in the constructor.

```
I initialize it as a member variable. 
int32_t *myArray_;

When I use it in a method, I would:
this->myArray = new int32_t[50];

To delete it in the method I would call delete on the array:
delete [] this->myArray;

What is the proper call in the destructor?
~MyDestructor(){

    delete this->myArray_;
    or delete [] this->myArray_;

}
```

I have the same question about vector pointers:

```
I initialize it as a member variable. 
std::vector<MyObject*> *myVector_;

When I use it in a method, I would:
this->myVector_ = new std::vector<MyObject*>();


//pushback some objects

To delete the vector in the method I would iterate the vector and delete its objects, then    delete the vector;

 for(std::vector<MyObject*>::iterator itr = this->myVector_->begin(); 
 its != this->myVector->end(); ++ itr){

      delete (*itr);

}

delete this->myVector_;


What would be the proper way to clean it up in the destructor?
would I just delete the vector?

delete this->myVector;

or do I need to iterate the entire vector again?
```

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: `new[]` --> `delete[]` and `new` --> `delete`.

Comment: Why would you have a `vector<>*`?  `std::vector<>` is not going to put large allocations on the stack (internally it allocates objects from the heap), so there is _generally_ no good reason to dynamically allocate `std::vectors<>`.

Comment: @Chad There are valid reasons to use vector pointers; One would be if an API already had factories that hand you a vector, but you are responsible to destroy it.

Comment: The code does **not** have a "pointer to a[n] `int32_t` array". It has a pointer to an `int32_t`.

Comment: APIs that force memory management onto their users are evil.

Comment: @chad Okay, You're probably right, but I still have to work with the system that has been layed in place many years before I came here. I can't and do not want to change the wisdom of the mighty software architects, I just want to properly destroy the pointers to the objects.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Anything allocated with `new` should be deallocated with `delete`.

```
int* p = new int;
delete p;
```

Anything allocated with `new []` should be deallocated with `delete []`.

```
int* p = new int[10];
delete [] p;
```

Anything dynamically allocated and stored in a `vector`, needs to be manually deallocated:

```
std::vector<int*> v;
v.push_back(new int(1));
v.push_back(new int(2));

for(std::vector<int*>::iterator i = v.begin(), e = v.end(); i != e; ++i)
   delete (*i);
```

If, for some strange reason, you feel it is appropriate to dynamically allocate a `vector`, the same rules apply.

```
std::vector<int*>* v = new std::vector<int*>;
v->push_back(new int(1));
v->push_back(new int(2));

for(std::vector<int*>::iterator i = v->begin(), e = v->end(); i != v; ++i)
   delete (*i);

delete v;
```

But, I would suggest that the reasons to dynamically allocate a `std::vector` are few and far between.

In C++11, the best way to do this, is with `std::unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> p(new int);
// std::unique_ptr handles clean up for you


std::unique_ptr<int[]> p(new int[10]);
// std::unique_ptr handles clean up for you for arrays too!
```

If you have a member variable of a class, the same rules apply:

```
class Foo
{
   Foo()
      : bar_(new int)
      , bar2_(new int[20])
   {
   }

   ~Foo()
   {
      delete [] bar2_;
      delete bar_;
   }

   int* bar_;
   int* bar2_;
};
```

But even then, it makes more sense to have them as `std::unique_ptr`, you can even treat them as raw pointers in interfaces when required:

```
class Foo
{
   Foo()
     : bar_(new int)
     , bar2_(new int[20])
   {
   }

   int* get_bar()
   {
      return bar_.get();
   }

   int* get_bar2()
   {
      return bar2_.get();
   }

   std::unique_ptr<int> bar_;
   std::unique_ptr<int[]> bar2_;
};
```

Comment: The rule regarding delete/delete[] is not always right. Consider `typedef int mytype[42]; int* x = new mytype;`. Now you need to `delete[] x;` even though you used `new` and not `new[]`.

Comment: Thanks Chad. I really appreciate that. So, in the example on the int32_t*; In my method I initialize it to myArray = new int32_t[50]. In the method, I would delete it using delete[] myArray_, but in the destructor, I would use delete myArray_ because it is no longer defined as new int32_[50] ?

Comment: No, if you initialize it at with `new[]`, use `delete[]`, even if its in another (later) method.  I've updated my answer with a few more details.

Comment: @Chad: because you still have the wrong rule "Anything allocated with new should be deallocated with delete" at the top.

Comment: @etarion Can you explain why that is a problem?  Is the argument that smart pointers (such as `std::unique_ptr`) abstract that rule away, where you may see a `new` in user code without a corresponding `delete` in user code?

Comment: @chad: See my first comment. There are cases (specifically array typedefs) where you use `new` (without the braces), and need to use `delete[]`.

Comment: @Chad: Know this is an old post, but in the for loop line you describe:

for(std::vector<int*>::iterator i = v->begin(), e = v->end(); i != v; ++i)

Should that read i != e?