# Proper way to destroy a map that has pointer values

Tags: c++, pointers, stl

I am using `std::map` to map string values to `MyType *`. My map declaration looks like this:

```
map<string, MyType *> *my_map = new map<string, MyType>;
```

`my_map` is a private member variable of one of my classes. My problem is that I am unsure of how to destroy the map. When deleteing the map, I would also like to call `delete` on all of the `MyType *` contained in the map. Here is my current destructor:

```
my_map->erase(my_map->begin(), my_map->end());
delete my_map;
```

Will this delete the pointers contained in the map, or do I need to iterate through the map to delete each pointer before calling erase?

Comment: The later - `map` (and most (if not all ?) containers in the standard library) has not been designed to delete any pointer it contains upon destruction.

Comment: Ok thanks. The documentation I read on it wasn't very clear. It read: `This effectively reduces the container size by the number of elements removed, which are destroyed.`

Comment: That's a common misunderstanding - the _pointers_ themselves are indeed destroyed, but that doesn't change the state of the memory location they point to.

Comment: Why the obsession with pointers and `new`?  What's wrong with this: `map<string, MyType> my_map;`

Comment: Something went wrong in the design. Why does the container own pointer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proper destruction of pointers to objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13844963/proper-destruction-of-pointers-to-objects) and probably hundreds of other questions

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_map.html

Comment: I just edited the question adding "stl" and "pointers" tags.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're not using smart pointers? They could solve this for you pretty well.

Comment: "I am using std::map to map string values to MyType\*." Isn't he using std::map to map MyType* to string keys?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pointers merely point. When using raw pointers, you need to know which part of your app owns the resources that the pointers point to. If they are owned by the map, you will need to iterate over the map and call delete on each pointer before the map is destroyed. But if the map just holds pointers to objects that are owned by other parts of your code, you don't need to do anything.

A safer solution is to use shared_ptr to manage object lifetime, which will ensure that the object gets deleted properly when the last shared_ptr is destroyed. You can store shared_ptrs inside the map and if no other shared_ptr instances reference the objects within the map, the objects will be destroyed when the map is destroyed, as desired.

Answer (score 4):

If you use [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) instead of raw pointers, everything will be cleaned up for you automatically.

```
// header:
using MapType = std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<MyType>>;
shared_ptr<MapType> my_map;

// usage:
my_map.emplace("foo", std::make_shared<MyType>());

// destructor:
MyClass::~MyClass()
{
    // nothing!
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> Will this delete the pointers contained in the map [...]?

No, given the code you have provided, you will leak every member of the map.

As a rule, for every `new` there must be a matching `delete`.  You have a `delete` for the map, but none for the elements within.

The most correct solution to this problem is to not use dynamic allocation at all.  Just store `MyType`s directory, if possible:

`map<string, MyType>`

... and instead of dynamically allocating the `map` itself, store that automatically:

```
map<string,MyType> my_map;
```

If automatic storage duration is not possible for some reason, then use a smart pointer for the dynamic allocations.  Given a C++11 compiler, use `unique_ptr` (or, rarely, `shared_ptr` or even `weak_ptr`) for the elements in the `map`:

```
map<string, unique_ptr<MyType>> my_map;
```

(Given a C++03 compiler, use the Boost equivalents thereof.)  Then when `my_map` is destroyed, all the elements will be `delete`d.

Baring all of this, if you are in a situation where none of the above will work for you (I would by highly suspect), then you will need to iterate the map youself:

```
struct deleter
{
  template <typename T> operator() (const T& rhs) const
  { 
    delete rhs.second;
  }
};

for_each (my_map->begin(), my_map->end(), deleter());
```

In C++11, this could be made a lambda, something along the line of:

```
for_each (my_map->begin(), my_map->end(), [](auto item) -> void
{
  delete item.second;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In modern C++, just make your life easier and use pointers *only* if strictly required.

You started with this code:

> ```
> map<string, MyType *> *my_map = new map<string, MyType>;
> ```

The first thing you can do is to consider using a `std::map` instance as data member, instead of a *pointer* to it.

Then, if `MyType` is not super-expensive to copy and its instances are only owned by the map, just consider a simple `map` from `string` to `MyType` (instead of `MyType*`):

```
// my_map data member - no pointers --> automatically deleted in class destructor
map<string, MyType> my_map;
```

If you really need a map containing pointers, consider using **smart pointers**, like `std::shared_ptr` (available in C++11/14) for shared ownership, or `std::unique_ptr` for unique non-shared ownership.
(If you target C++98/03, an option is to use `boost::shared_ptr`. Since there is no move semantics, you can't have `unique_ptr`, which is heavily based on the move semantics feature.)
e.g.:

```
// Map containing _smart_ pointers 
//     --> default destructor is fine (no need for custom delete code)
map<string, shared_ptr<MyType>> my_map;
```

As you can see, using *value semantics* (instead of raw pointers), or *smart pointers*, you can simplify your code and use the **automatic destruction** provided by C++.